# After mysql_real_escape_string, apostrophes showing up in Twitter with a preceding backslash

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, mysql-real-escape-string

In the code below, the second line posts `$comment` to Twitter.

When `$comment` below has apostrophes in it, they are preceded in the Tweet with a backslash.  How can I get rid of the backslash in Twitter?

```
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);

$tweet->post("statuses/update", array("status" => "$comment $fullurl"));
```

Comment: If you are no using UTF-8 for the database connection, this could be the reason

Comment: Unless `$tweet->post()` interacts with the database, you are not supposed to use a database escaping function.

Comment: You could also switch from `MRES` to `PDO` and stop worrying about quotes _and_ SQL injection.

Comment: @mario... Else in the code I'm putting it into a MySQL database.

Comment: Then that one variable can't serve two different purposes.

Comment: Aren't you posting to twitter>? What's the mysql for? Are you getting tweets from a db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `magic_quotes` are set to on in PHP conf? See [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)

You can do also

```
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['comment']));
```

Comment: Wouldn't that expose the $comment variable to SQL injection?

Comment: No, because `mysql_real_escape_string` exactly prevents from injection. With `stripslashes` you can prevent double escaping.

Answer (score 3):

There's no SQL visible in all of this, so there is no point in calling `mysql_real_escape_string`. In fact, since you say you're posting to Twitter, I doubt there's any SQL involved *at all* on your side (at least not for that part).

Escaping should always be done as the very last thing, *immediately* before actually using the variable in an SQL statement, and *only* for the context of that SQL statement. If your `$tweet->post` function does some SQL on your side as well, have that function do the escaping necessary.